# How to read an unsigned int from a std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>?

Tags: pointers, c++11, smart-pointers, unsigned-integer

So basically I'm working on a file reader and the binary file gets loaded into a `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>` containing all the bytes from the file.

I'm trying to read an unsigned int from the start of it. Usually, if it were just a raw pointer (`unsigned char*`) it would be as follows:

```
unsigned int magic = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(buffer));
```

However, I'm currently trying to the same, where buffer is the smart pointer. So far I've came up with this:

```
unsigned int magic = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(classFile_.get()));
```

Upon outputting `magic` like this:

```
std::cout << std::hex << magic;
```

I get `1`. Where I should be getting: 0xbebafeca (this is a Java class file reader, 0xCAFEBABE is the unsigned int magic number).

Any ideas as to why it's not working? I'm also not sure if storing a smart pointer for the `unsigned char*` is good practice rather than doing something like storing a raw pointer and deleting the allocated array in the de-constructor.

Comment: Your `reinterpret_cast` is dangerous due to alignment concerns.

Comment: I'd normally use a `std::vector<unsigned char>` over `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>` but technically there's nothing wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah, I was considering using a vector. I'm just unsure as to why it's outputting `1`.

Comment: I have no idea. Code looks like it ought to work (on most machines)

Comment: Looks like an endian issue to me.

Comment: @sithereal Meh, not sure what you mean. I basically read all the values from the file header and for most of them, since they go little endian, I use bitwise operations to reverse the byte order, works fine. I'm looking into a better way to store the `unsigned char*` as a member of the reader class.

Comment: @MooingDuck "Nothing wrong" other than breaking strict aliasing and alignment requirements?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/MJRRL38195) To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code you haven't shown. I'd start by checking that the buffer pointed to by `classFile_.get()` actually contains the bytes you believe it contains.